# Assigning a value from csv file to variable in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I'm new to this site and to programming generally. I need to get a value from a specific cell in a csv file (data is comma separated and none of the data contains spaces) and assign it in bash to a variable (so it becomes constant value), to use it in next operations. For example:

```
x="c8 cell value"
```

Could someone please help me with this?

As I said I'm not an expert and if someone could explain me how should I do it and what every command in the potential solution means would be perfect.

Comment: Post an example of the relevant csv lines.

Comment: Since this question isn't an exact duplicate since it's also about assigning variables in Bash to the output of a command... you can use:     x=\`awk -F"," ' FNR == 8 {print $3 } '\`   The backticks around the command are the key here.

Comment: Not a duplicate. The OP wants to assign it to a variable, and wants that variable to be a constant value (thus requiring the "readonly" keyword.)